# Call function when time changes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Being new to react , this all is really confusing and new to me , so I apologise if I'm making some obvious oversight.

Im making a stopwatch and implementing the seconds for starters. However; Im confused as to how i'll implement the on display seconds number to update when each second passes.

This is what I'm doing right now

```
function App() {
  const [time , updateTime] = React.useState(0);
  var startsec = 0;

  
  //UpdateTime should get triggered when next second passes
  const UpdateTime = () => {
    //Update time variable with the new seconds elapsed
  }

  //Should run every second or something
  const CheckTimeUpdation = () => {
    currentsec = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000.0);
    console.log(currentsec);
    if(currentsec > startsec){
      UpdateTime(currentsec-startsec);
    }
  }

  const GetStartTime = () => {
    startsec = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000.0);
  }

  //Clock component just gets a number and displays it on the screen
  return (<div className = "App">
    <Clock timerSeconds= {time}/>
    <div>
      <button onClick={GetStartTime}></button>
    </div>
    </div>);

}

export default App;
```

Date.now() function gets the miliseconds passed since 1970 (hence the division by 1000 to make them into seconds) and I find the difference between when the button was clicked and current one and passs that to the time component to display.

**How do I make the CheckTimeUpdation function run every second or so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `setInterval()` method (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

However your code so far has some issues:

On the button click, `getStartTime` runs and it updates the value of `startsec`. Firstly, this does not cause the component to re-render, and so the component will not update and you will see nothing changing on your screen. Also, if you did get your component to re-render, you will notice that `startsec` will be 0 again on the next re-render, so re-assigning `startsec` like how you did likely doesn't do what you want it to. If you want to persist values between rerenders, you can use `useState` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) or `useRef` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Now i'm assuming you want to start the timer when the button is clicked. What you need is to start the interval (via `setInterval`) on the button click, and update time every 1000ms.

You'd also want to clear the interval once you don't need it anymore, using the `clearInterval()` method. You'll need to save the id returned from `setInterval()` initially in order to clear it later.

Below I have written a short example using this idea with `setInterval` on button click to help you:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState("paused");
  const [timeElapsed, setTimeElapsed] = useState(0);
  const intervalId = useRef(0);

  const isRunning = timerState === "running";
  const isPaused = timerState === "paused";

  const onStartTimer = () => {
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeElapsed((time) => time + 1);
    }, 1000);
    setTimerState("running");
  };

  const onStopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    intervalId.current = 0;
    setTimerState("paused");
  };

  const onClearTimer = () => {
    setTimeElapsed(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{timeElapsed}</h1>
      {isPaused && <button onClick={onStartTimer}>Start timer</button>}
      {isRunning && <button onClick={onStopTimer}>Stop timer</button>}
      {!!timeElapsed && <button onClick={onClearTimer}>Clear timer</button>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval in the GetStartTime Function.

```
const GetStartTime = () => {
    startsec = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000.0);
    setInterval(() => CheckTimeUpdation(), 1000);
  }
```